# Can I use pandas replace function to replace different values in multiple columns with unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following simple problem, imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 'dude', 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['5', '5', 'dude', '5', '5']})
print(df)

     A     B     C
0  foo     5     5
1    1  dude     5
2    2     7  dude
3    3     8     5
4    4     9     5
```

Now I want to replace values `['foo','dude','dude']`in columns A, B, and C, respectively all with their own unique values. I was able to accomplish this using pandas `replace` function.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('foo', value = 68 ).astype(float)
df['B'] = df['B'].replace('dude', value = 46).astype(float)
df['C'] = df['C'].replace('dude', value = 86).astype(float)
```

This works, but I know that previously in a lot of code I have written there has been a much simpler, and effective way to accomplish similar problems.  I have an intuitive feeling that there is a better way to accomplish this, however I am unsure what it may be.

Here is what I tried.

```
dict1={'A':{'foo':68},'B':{'dude': 46}, 'C':{'dude':86}}
dfclean = df.replace(dict1)
```

but to no avail.  Is it the most efficient way to replace these each with their own line?

EDIT:

Wow, I am a complete moron... The solution I wrote above actually works, I was just printing df, rather than dfclean.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `df.replace(dict1)` works fine for me on Pandas v0.23.4.

Comment: Really? Is that syntax correct?

For me it does not seem to be working. I get the error `Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'`

I am entering it verbatim as above.

Comment: Yup, tried & tested. `replace` is one of those functions which have many different uses depending on what you're trying to achieve. Different Pandas versions may have an impact.

Comment: Nevermind it did not work...

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  pd.__version__

Comment: You are right, it works... I made a mistake in printing the original data frame.  Oof, too much coding today. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of values to be replaced, then map() is a faster option than .replace (about 100x for me). The downside is that with map, you don't have regex available for substring replacement - in case you need it.

See if this works for you:

```
# Map the dictionary to the whole dataframe
df= df.map(dict1).fillna(df)
```

Using fillna here prevents NaNs from showing up in case the line isn't replaced.